# Mutli site redirect JS

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

We have a mutlisite drupal site which one of the sites (for example site1.com) goes to a mobile site and site 2 doesn't. So the following code been written

```
(function(){
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
var refer = document.referrer
    if(refer.indexOf("site1") ==-1)
    window.location = "http://www.site1.com/mobile/";
  }
})();
```

So in Theory, the code above should redirect to the mobile site setup for site1 and site2 should go to it's normal site. However this code is causing both sites to redirect to site1 mobile site.

Comment: What is the value of "document.referrer" ? If it is not the value you expected, it will go to site 1. This is the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It's odd then as why both site1 and site2 go to the site1's mobile. if I changed the -1 to 1 would this help narrow done for just site1?

Answer (score 0):

upon re-reading, I think this solves your problem,
edit this line, of your original code:

```
if(refer.indexOf("site1") ==-1)
```

into this:

```
if(refer.indexOf("site1") !=-1)
```

The old code redirected your page to site1's mobile version when you **did not** have site1's referrer.

The new code redirects you to site1's mobile version if it **does** have site1's referrer.

If the document.referrer does not contain "site1" it could be because there was no referrer, which is the case when someone enters the URL manually, or clicks the link from outside the browser.

It is likely that you may need to rely on document.location instead, which will virtually always match the address initially displayed in the URL bar of the browser.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Hi Joeppie. Thanks for the information however from your answer you're saying the old code redirected when it did not have site1's referrer but it is redirecting site 1 and 2

Comment: To re-iterate: what is the value of document.referrer? The suggested replacement likely **never** redirects, which would indicate the document.referrer **never** contains "site1"